# Ошибка при работе с Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql

Доброе время суток, может кто ни будь по русски объяснить из за чего может возникать ошибка в Doctrine 
$provider->setUser($user); // $user = "azazaza"
$provider->save();

> Couldn't call Doctrine_Core::set(), second argument should be an
>   instance of Doctrine_Record or Doctrine_Null when setting one-to-one
>   references.

Я перевл текст ошибки, но смысл так и не понял. Поясните чего ему не нравится.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Данная ошибка говорит о том, что второй аргумент функции `Doctrine_Core::set()` должен быть экземпляром `Doctrine_Record` или `Doctrine_Null`